# How do I maximize a form from an other form?

Tags: forms, delphi, taskbar, maximize, maximize-window

My program has two forms. At a certain point while running, both forms will be shown - one atop of the other. I want to be able to maximize the bottom form while focused on the front one.

I played around a bit with `TForm.BorderStyle := bsNone` and `ShowWindowAsync(Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE)` as it seems to be the only thing that maximizes to fullscreen.

This, however, maximizes the current and wrong form.

Is there any way to **completely** maximize (to fullscreen) a form from inside another one?

Comment: Try `TheOtherForm.WindowState := wsMaximized;` where `TheOtherForm` is the `Name` of the form, not its type. Alternatively, call `ShowWindowAsync(TheOtherForm.Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);` **Neither of these, though, makes the window grow to cover the taskbar on my Windows 10 system.**

Comment: If you can explain why you specifically want to hide (prevent use of?) the taskbar, there might be other ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: So by "_completely maximize_" you just mean [fullscreen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullscreen)?

Comment: Yes @AmigoJack, fullscreen is correct. While writing I just forgot that the word exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

With the help of a comment made by Tom Brunberg, I have found that although `ShowWindowAsync(TheOtherForm.Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE)` does not make the form completely fullscreen, it works on removing the `"Async"`.

Thus,

```
TForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
ShowWindow(TheOtherForm.Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

is a working solution in this case.